# Is there a better way to return an object and constructor from a constructor function?

Tags: javascript, object, constructor, return, return-value

I'm trying to return an object along with the constructor function. I have something working but it's kind of ugly and was hoping there was a better way.

```
function Something(val) {
  if (!(this instanceof Something))
    return new Something(val)

  let Constructor = function() {
    return function(val) {
      return new Something(val)
    }
  }

  let obj = new Constructor()
  obj.test = val
  return obj
}

let a = Something('a')
let b = new Something('b')
let c = b('c')

console.log(a) // { [Function] test: 'a' }
console.log(b) // { [Function] test: 'b' }
console.log(c) // { [Function] test: 'c' }
```

Thanks for any help.

**Edit:**

Upon further consideration, I believe more explanation is needed and also decided to approach the problem from a different angle.

Okay, let me see if I can hypothetically articulate my problem. I have a Factory that should resolve to another "class" (although using ES5 function prototypes). This other "class" should be able to have an optional class constructor function along with what we call "class methods". This custom class also needs to be an instance so that it can store data from within it's methods (referring to `this`)

Ideally, we want the following syntaxes.

```
const something = Something('customClass') // new keyword is optional
something.someMethod()
// or
something(optionalConfig).someMethod()
```

In addition to calling the class with the optional constructor, we must also instantiate a new instance.

So that these lines are acting on separate instances:

```
something.someMethod() // refers to the instance already created
something(optionalConfig).someMethod() // new instance
something(otherOptionalConfig).someMethod() // new instance
```

Comment: What exactly is it that you don't like about your (apparently working) code?

Comment: Primarily because assigning another object requires me to loop through the object and call Object.defineProperty in order to merge the function with the object together.

Comment: The code you posted doesn't do anything like that however.

Comment: That is true. I needed to show a minimal example to ask the question for S.O.

Comment: What is this code trying to achieve, what is your real-world problem? A constructor should never be used to construct other constructors (like `b`). Why do you want all of your instances to be functions? Should `a` and `b` behave any different from each other? Why are you calling `Something` with `new` at all?

Comment: Why would an object need to check if its type is itself? What’s wrong with just using `new` so you’ll get a new instance? In other words, what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @Bergi this is a simplified example. In real world use, this is essentially a factory class that can instantiate new instances from calling it like a constructor. A and B SHOULD absolutely behave differently depending on what code (functions) they're exporting.

Comment: Suggestions: 1) look on MDN [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/constructor) and [here](https://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-design-patterns-singleton/): *JavaScript Design Patterns: The Singleton*.  2) Note that "Constructor()" (camel-case) != "constructor()" (ES6 special function).  3) If that doesn;t help, please clarify your use case: what exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @Kokodoko I want the new keyword to be optional, some of which I don't feel the need to explain myself.

Comment: @paulsm4 I thought I had made that fairly obvious. I want a Factory function which can return its own constructor along with object properties. Just like the example does above. However want to know if there is an alternative way to do that due to having to iterate over `ob2` keys and use `Object.defineProperty`. Essentially merging an object with a function.

Comment: Calling a function is different from creating an instance, from a software design point of view. Sorry but I can’t help but wonder why you would want it to behave the same :)

Comment: If I MUST give even one example, it's so that new developers don't call the factory without new on accident and get unintended consequences. I can solve that small issue with just two lines of code. Yes, it encourages bad practices - however I want to give new developers an actual chance to learn how to develop and minimize the amount of mistakes they can make while using my library.

Comment: @LeviRoberts What is a "factory class", do you mean a class factory? Why does `b` need to be callable/constructible - isn't it an instance? What do you mean by "exporting" - in your example `a` and `b` are behaving identical?

Comment: @LeviRoberts Yes, you can avoid accidents from missing `new` with just two lines of code. But what is the rest of your code, after those two lines, supposed to do?

Comment: I question why my motives are being challenged, rather than collaborating on a creative solution.

Comment: Object.assign() doesn't work?  does it fail to copy getters/setters?  
And that doesn't really work at all?  You can't 'return obj' when called with 'new' and A and B are both created through 'new' which is going to return an object that is not 'obj'; it was kind of a wrong example to start with...
Need to do like 'if instanceof is the function' throw an error, 'do not call with 'new''

Comment: @LeviRoberts I cannot help with a solution if I don't understand the [actual problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377). The code you posted in your question is indeed ugly and imo doing weird things, but without knowing the constraints on what is considered "working" I cannot suggest an alternative. I'm not challenging your motives, I would like you to state them.

Comment: @Bergi thanks for your response. I've updated the question to hopefully explain the challenge more appropriately.

Comment: Ah, thanks. The only thing that I don't understand is what the difference between `Something("customClass1")` and `Something("customClass2")` would become - would they have different methods behaving differently (and where do those come from), or are they really all instances of the same class with just a different initial configuration?

Comment: Btw, the usual approach to this problem is not to make the `something` instances callable (*be* a constructor), but to give them a factory method that creates another instance (*have* a constructor) to be called e.g. as `something1 = something.with(optionalConfig); something2 = something.with(otherOptionalConfig);`. What you are trying to do is [achievable as well](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54774494/1048572) though.

Comment: @Bergi yes, customClass1 and customClass2 COULD have different methods and properties. For now, they are just separate instances with their own properties. They come from their own 'customClass' files which I'm importing async from the Factory. I'm familiar with the traditional approach however refuse to give up on my alternative syntax. I have it working just not as well as I'd like.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be looking for something along the lines of

```
function Custom(config) {
  function customInstance(moreConfig) {
    return new Custom(config + moreConfig); // not calling Something!
  }
  Object.setPrototypeOf(customInstance, Custom.prototype);
  customInstance.config = config;
  customInstance.test = true
  return customInstance;
}
Custom.prototype = Object.create(Function.prototype);
Custom.prototype.method = function() { … };

const constructors = {Custom, …};
function Something(className) {
  if (!constructors.hasOwnProperty(className)) throw new Error("…");
  return new constructors[className];
}
```

Given that a `Custom` constructor and also the `Something` factory returns a (function) object anyway, the `new` operator is optional anyway and you don't need to check for it explicitly.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. A couple notes, it appears that this requires the custom classes to create it's own instances and set prototype chain rather than the factory (Something). This wouldn't work for our use cases. In addition to that, I believe `Object.setPrototypeOf` is not ES5 (although there is a polyfill). Lastly, it appears theres much more going on here than simply creating a new instance of the Factory and returning the class Constructor function with new inside the factory (creating a new instance of the class), as in my example.

Comment: There is one more issue with this and that is you must know before-hand of your custom classes with your `constructors` object. Unless you also show an example where you can dynamically add those, using ES5 syntax.

Comment: @LeviRoberts Nothing in your question asked for ES5, so it usually is assumed that one can use contemporary features :-)

Comment: @LeviRoberts You were not clear about where the classes come from, so I just assumed that you could write their code as well. (In the example in your question, the only example class was even defined *within* `Something`). Of course all the stuff that allows calling instances can be abstracted out if you have multiple classes, please edit your question to give an example on how you want to define them.

Comment: @LeviRoberts The `constructors` object is a simple lookup table of classes by name, and it's mutable - you can add your classes whenever you want. In the comments you mentioned "*They come from their own 'customClass' files which I'm importing async from the Factory.*" - just do that here, I don't know what exactly you are doing to dynamically import them so I chose a simplified solution in the answer.

Comment: you are mistaken. I did ask about ES5 quote: `(although using ES5 function prototypes)`. Perhaps I should have been more clear, if so - apologies. In my question, the Factory is the thing that builds the custom classes. I don't think the code that constructs them is important for our discussion here. The constructors object you use here also uses the spread/rest syntax. What would I use as the key of the object to mutate it?

Comment: @LeviRoberts Not spread syntax (`...`), that's just an ellipsis (`…`) for more things to be filled in there :-) I used the `className` as the key here, but if you're doing it differently anyway that'll hardly matter.

Comment: @LeviRoberts "the Factory is the thing that builds the custom classes*" - I had assumed they didn't all have the same blueprint, so I put them externally as if to be imported. If you think it's not important, I won't be more specific in my answer regarding that.