# Can javascript's `new` operator ever return a callable object?

Tags: javascript, metaprogramming

Нello! Sometimes an API could be written especially cleanly if instances of classes are callable. This seems to be especially useful when a class has an operation which is much more common than any other operation.

For example, consider a library for defining Trees, where each `Node` in the tree has a value and an indexed list of child nodes:

```
let Node = function(value, children) { /* ... */ };
Node.prototype = { /* ... */ };

let root = new Node('root', [
  new Node('child1', [
    new Node('grandchild11', []),
    new Node('grandchild12', [])
  ]),
  new Node('child2', [
    new Node('grandchild21', []),
    new Node('grandchild22', [])
  ])
]);
```

I would say that a `Node` has an operation which is much more common than any other operation: to get a child at a particular index:

```
root.getChild(1); // Returns the "child2" node (0-based indexing)
```

I would say that this operation is so common, it would be very readable and clean to achieve the same result via the following:

```
root(1);
```

However to enable syntax like this, `root` would have to be a callable object (and therefore the `Node` constructor would need to return a callable object). Such functionality would be really cool when chained!:

```
root(0)(1); // Returns `grandchild12`
```

It's imaginable that with such syntax other types could be passed, for example passing a function could return the node which matches the search:

```
root(node => node.value === 'child1')(node => node.value === 'grandchild11');
```

Is there some clever (metaprogramming?) technique which could allow javascript's `new` keyword to return a callable object, and facilitate syntax such as this?

Note that for more complex APIs, polymorphism becomes an important feature! I'd like to preserve the object's prototype chain, if possible.

NOTE:

Jsperf comparing callable instances (`root(0)`) and instance methods (`root.getChild(0)`) seems to shows me (Chrome 72.0.3626) that callable instances are [a tiny bit slower](https://jsperf.com/callable-class-instance-vs-instance-method).

Comment: You can explicitly return a function in the constructor...

Comment: Your constructor can return a `function` instance with the node properties attached to it. If a constructor is invoked as a constructor (with `new`) and it has an explicit `return` that returns *any* kind of object, then that object is used as the result of the `new` instead of the automatically-constructed plain object.

Comment: Ahh is that possible, without losing the prototype chain? That may be exactly what I'm looking for!

Comment: `Object.setPrototypeOf(function someCallableNodeObj(){}, nodeProto)` (and ensure that `nodeProto.__proto__` is `Function`, or has it somewhere in the chain. You can do `nodeProto = Object.create(Function)` or similar)

Comment: (if you are using these trees for high performance operations, I wouldn't use the recommendation above though...)

Comment: @apsillers `Function.prototype` not `Function` to be exact

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, a call via `new` can return any kind of object, including functions. It is true that calling a function with `new` will automatically fill `this` with a newly-created object, but you need not have `this` be the return value of your constructor: simply `return` any other object.

Really what you want here is have a `Node` be a kind of function. Simply have your `Node` constructor return a function object with the appropriate properties and prototype chain. You'll need to ensure

1. The return value of the constructor is an actual function
2. The prototype of that function value has been manually changed to your `Node` prototype object
3. Your `Node` prototype object inherits from `Function.prototype` so that your `Node` instances get Function methods like `call` and `bind`

For example:

```
function Node(value) {
    // build the function to return
    var returnFunc = function getChild() { /*...*/ };

    // set instance properties like `value`, `children`, whatever
    returnFunc.value = value;

    // inherit Node methods and make `this instanceof Node` be true
    Object.setPrototypeOf(returnFunc, Node.prototype);

    // or non/barely-standard, but with older support:
    //    returnFunc.__proto__ = Node.prototype

    // you must explicitly `return` a value, or else `this` is used
    return returnFunc;
}

// Node instances should inherit Function methods like `call` and `bind`
// so Node must be a prototypal child of Function
Node.prototype = Object.create(Function.prototype);

// set Node inherited prototype methods
Node.prototype.getChild = function() { /*...*/ }

// optional: change the `toString` representation to reflect Node `value` instead of function code
Node.prototype.toString = function() { return "I'm a Node: " + this.value; }
```